# Apache doesn't use all bandwith

Tags: upload, apache2, limit

I'm using apache 2.4.1 on windows and I'm trying to optimize my website www.xgclan.com loading speed with http://www.webpagetest.org.

I noticed that the download time is quite long in the report.

Today I downloaded the Windows 8 preview to my server as mirror, I put it on my apache server and tried downloading it with my home connection, the speed was only 500 KB/s.

My server has an 100 Mb/s duplex connection and task manager indicates that only 7% of the bandwidth is used.

I have 120Mb/s down at home and I ran a speedtest to make sure its not an issue with my home connection.

Downloading works fine on the server so I think its an issue with apache or windows server 2008 R2.
Can anybody help me so I can use my full 100 Mb/s upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by EnableSendfile on, after turning this off I was able to use the full connection speed.